# Preventing saving multiple messages in database for short period of time

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a problem which I can't understand from where is came. It doesn't happen often, like 2-3 times per 2-3 months.

On the site I have form from which user can send message to admin. Everything is working fine but from time to time one message is saved 30-40 times in database with difference from 1 second.

May be is page load issue. I doubt that user can click 30+ times on submit button BEFORE the page load. The code in my controller is also very simple

```
public function indexSubmit() {
    $validatorRules = array(
        'message' => 'required|min:5',
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/messages')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::all());
    }

    $message = new Message;
    $message->user_id = self::$user['user_id'];
    $message->text = Input::get('message');
    $message->read_state = 0;
    $message->from_admin = 0;
    $message->save();

    return Redirect::to('/messages')->with('message_success', 'Message sent.');
}
```

What I think one solution could be to somehow limit the submits to 1 per 10 seconds for example. How can I accomplish this?

Tried this and doesn't seems to work

```
$message = new Message;
    if($message->created_at + 10 < time()) {
        // insert
    }
    else{

        // error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone could just be spamming your form, you could also add a CAPTCHA or AYAH test. If you want to limit the requests, store the last request `time()` somewhere and compare against it.

```
if($stored_time + 10 < time())
```

Comment: It's e-commerce and the massages are from customer which actually made order.. so I doubt that he/she will just spamming with same message 30+ times. But who knows...

Comment: Updated my question with what I've tried in the controller but doesn't seems to work